# How can I use the gallery uploader in custom gutenberg blocks

Tags: javascript, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm developing a custom gallery block for my wordpress theme and was wondering if it is possible to use the already existing gallery creator in wordpress for this. I can't find anything on it on the web, if you don't understand what I'm talking about, here's a screenshot of it:
[image: Edit panel]
[image: Upload button]
Thank you for any help provided!